# Intercepting physical push to talk button of the Rexon BT-28HC

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a Rexon BT-28HC bluetooth speaker mic and I'd like to react (from my Android app) to when its physical push to talk button is pressed. This must be possible somehow, because Zello is able to do it.

As far as I can tell the Rexon connects to Android both as a speaker and a mic. I.e. once paired it acts both as a mic and a speaker.

I tried capturing a ton of intents, but to no avail.

Many thanks in advance,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I found the solution. I need to create a (bluetooth) serial link to the device, and then it will send me some bytes on button press and release.